# how to return a property based on another property condition using LINQ in .NET Core

Tags: json, linq, .net-core

```
{
"value": [{
            "odata.type": "SP.User",
            "odata.id": "https://www.test.com/_api/Web/GetUserById(37)",
            "odata.editLink": "Web/GetUserById(37)",
            "Id": 37,
            "IsHiddenInUI": false,
            "LoginName": "i:0#.w|domain\\jos",
            "Title": "Mr joseph",
            "PrincipalType": 1,
            "Email": "joe@yopmail.com",
            "IsEmailAuthenticationGuestUser": false,
            "IsShareByEmailGuestUser": false,
            "IsSiteAdmin": false,
            "UserId": {
                "NameId": "s-1-5-21-2613750078-2161710047-3166685486-1473",
                "NameIdIssuer": "urn:office:idp:activedirectory"
            }
        }, {
            "odata.type": "SP.User",
            "odata.id": "https://www.test.com/_api/Web/GetUserById(90)",
            "odata.editLink": "Web/GetUserById(90)",
            "Id": 90,
            "IsHiddenInUI": false,
            "LoginName": "i:0#.w|domain\\pam",
            "Title": "anthony",
            "PrincipalType": 1,
            "Email": "anthony@yopmail.com",
            "IsEmailAuthenticationGuestUser": false,
            "IsShareByEmailGuestUser": false,
            "IsSiteAdmin": false,
            "UserId": {
                "NameId": "s-1-5-21-2613750078-2161710047-3166685486-1437",
                "NameIdIssuer": "urn:office:idp:activedirectory"
            }
        }
}
```

after deserializing this JSON I want to get the Title based on the Id so lets say if the Id = 37 I want to return a string that contain Mr joseph. is it possible to do this using LINQ? thank you for your help in advance...

I am desiralizing to this class:

```
public class UsersInformationValue
    {
        [JsonProperty("odata.type")]
        public string Odata_Type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("odata.id")]
        public string Odata_Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("odata.editlink")]
        public string Odata_EditLink { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public bool IsHiddenInUI { get; set; }
        public string LoginName { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int PrincipalType { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public bool IsEmailAuthenticationGuestUser { get; set; }
        public bool IsShareByEmailGuestUser { get; set; }
        public bool IsSiteAdmin { get; set; }
        public UserIdDetails UserId { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What does your deserialization code look like?  (And any classes you are deserializing too)

Comment: @ErikPhilips I added the class that I am deserializing to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that easily with a projection.

```cs
var title = values.Where(v => v.Id == 37).Select(v => v.Title).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var title = values.FirstOrDefault(v => v.Id == 37)?.Title;
```

Comment: `?? (string)null;` is redundant as `?.Title` is literally the same thing and can be removed.